# pcap - Proper capitalization when referring to the file standard?

Tags: pcap, libpcap

How does one properly refer to a Packet Capture file in short hand when writing about it for documentation?

I see a mix between PCAP, PCap and pcap in various areas and wikis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to refer to a packet capture file is "a packet capture file"; "pcap"/"PCap"/"pcap" are often used to refer to a *particular type* of packet capture file, those packet capture files written in the format that libpcap/WinPcap supports for writing.  There are several other capture file formats, one of which Wireshark, and libpcap 1.1.0 and later, can read (pcap-ng), and several of which Wireshark can read (and some that Wireshark can't read).

The way I (as a core developer of libpcap, tcpdump, and Wireshark) would say is the proper way to refer to files in the aforementioned format is "pcap", with no extra capitalization; the "pcap" comes from "libpcap", not directly from "packet capture", and "libpcap" is not capitalized (it's a UN*X library, and those tend to have all-lower-case names, given that almost all UN*X file systems are case-sensitive).

Others may call it "PCAP", perhaps because a number of terms in the computer and networking fields are acronyms or other initialisms and they assume "PCAP" must be as well, or call it "PCap", because they think of it as standing for "Packet Capture" rather than referring to libpcap and WinPcap, but, then again, people also referred to Sun Microsystems as "SUN" (it did come from the Stanford University Network project, but it wasn't "Stanford University Network Microsystems", it was just "Sun Microsystems").